# How can I set a FreeMarker variable with an interpolated value? error: "You can't use "${" here as you are already in FreeMarker-expression-mode."?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am absolutly new in **FreeMarker** and I have the following problem working on a Spring MVC application that use this template engine.

So into a controller method I put an int representing the current year (2016) into the **model**, in this way:

```
model.addAttribute("annoCorrente", annoCorrente);
```

Then, into my FreeMarker page I have to assign this value to a variable, so I write the following expression:

```
<#assign a = ${annoCorrente}>
```

But in this way I obtain the following error message:

```
[col. 86] You can't use "${" here as you are already in FreeMarker-expression-mode. Thus, instead of ${myExpression}, just write myExpression. (${...} is only needed where otherwise static text is expected, i.e, outside FreeMarker tags and ${...}-s.)
```

Why? How can I correctly initizialize a FreeMarker variable with the value obtained from the model associated to this view?

Comment: `annoCorrente` is already a variable. Read more about FreeMarker model.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory, just use `<#assign a = annoCorrente>`.

Comment: Ok, I know that it is alredy a variable but how can I use it to assign its value to another variable?

Answer (score 3):

Change `<#assign a = ${annoCorrente}>` to `<#assign a = annoCorrente>`

(or you can do `<#assign a = "${annoCorrente}">` but this is not recommended)